# How to assign role to admin user Programmatically?

Tags: magento-1.7, role

I need to assign a user role to admin user programmatically. How can I? I tried some methods like,

```
try {
$user->setRoleIds(array(<role_id>))
    ->setRoleUserId($user->getUserId())
    ->saveRelations();

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
```

But when we apply the above code, the database get corrupted and gets an Error - `"Parent Role id 'G5' does not exist"`.

This is because, when I apply the above code, the admin user with parent role Id is get deleted and I cant access the database If I recreate it again!

Can anyone point out a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange! But finaly got a solution from [here](http://blog.magikcommerce.com/how-to-create-an-admin-account-from-magento-code/).

Gave a try catch like this,

```
         try {
          $role = Mage::getModel("admin/role");
          $role->setParent_id(5);
          $role->setTree_level(1);
          $role->setRole_type('U');
          $role->setUser_id($user_id);
          $role->save();
          echo "Your username: ".$username.", and password: ".$password;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            }
```

and it Worked. Here `parent Id` is my custom role id. `$user_id` is the id of user to whome role should be attached.

Answer (score 3):

It seams you are doing it OK. It all depends on the values you use.
This piece of code worked for me. Assuming `$id` is the admin id in question:

```
$user = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load($id);
$user->setRoleIds(array(5))
    ->setRoleUserId($user->getUserId())
    ->saveRelations();
```

5 is the id of the role. It even works with a role id that does not exist. It just removes any role from the admin user.